# How would I get a BufferedImage from an OpenGL window?

Tags: java, opengl, bufferedimage

I'm coding a Java LWJGL game, and everything's going along great, except whenever I try to figure out a way to create a BufferedImage of the current game area. I've searched the internet, browsed all of the opengl functions, and I am getting no where... Anyone have any ideas? Here's all I have so far, but it only makes a blank .png:

```
if(Input.getKeyDown(Input.KEY_F2)) {
    try {
        String fileName = "screenshot-" + Util.getSystemTime(false);
        File imageToSave = new File(MainComponent.screenshotsFolder, fileName + ".png");
        int duplicate = 0;
        while(true) {
            duplicate++;
            if(imageToSave.exists() == false) {
                imageToSave.createNewFile();
                break;
            }
            imageToSave = new File(MainComponent.screenshotsFolder, fileName + "_" + duplicate + ".png");
        }
        imageToSave.createNewFile();

        // Create a buffered image:
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(MainComponent.WIDTH, MainComponent.HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        //Wrtie the new buffered image to file:
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", imageToSave);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002381/java-opengl-getting-the-image-of-a-canvas-as-a-bufferedimage

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect! I implemented those three functions into my Window.java class and set up the F2 key to call them, and I get an awesome little screenshot in the screenshots folder! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never actually write something into your BufferedImage.

### Read the Buffer

You can use [glReadPixels](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) to access the selected buffer. (I assume WIDTH and HEIGHT as your OpenGLContext dimensions.)

```
FloatBuffer imageData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3); 
GL11.glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_FLOAT, imageData);
imageData.rewind();
```

Use whatever parameters suit your needs best, I just picked floats randomly.

### Set the Image Data

You already figured out how to create and save your image, but in between you should also set some content to the image. You can do this with [BufferedImage().setRGB()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) (Note that I don't use a good naming as you do, to keep this example concise.)

```
// create image
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
     WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
);

// set content
image.setRGB(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, rgbArray, 0, WIDTH);

// save it
File outputfile = new File("Screenshot.png");
try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The most tricky part is now getting the rgbArray. The problems are that

1. OpenGL gives you three values (in this case, i.e. using `GL11.GL_RGB`), while the BufferedImage expects one value.
2. OpenGL counts the rows from bottom to top while BufferedImage counts from top to bottom.

### Calculate one Integer from three Floats

To get rid of problem one you have to calculate the integer value which fits the three number you get.
I will show this with a simple example, the color red which is `(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` in your FloatBuffer.

For the integer value it might be easy to think of numbers in hex values, as you might know from CSS where it's very common to name colors with those. Red would be `#ff0000` in CSS or in Java of course `0xff0000`.

Colors in RGB with integers are usually represented from 0 to 255 (or 00 to ff in hex), while you use 0 to 1 with floats or doubles. So first you have to map them to the correct range by simply multiplying the values by 255 and casting them to integers:

```
int r = (int)(fR * 255);
```

Now you can think of the hex value as just putting those numbers next to each other:

```
rgb = 255 0 0 = ff 00 00
```

To achieve this you can bitshift the integer values. Since one hex value (0-f) is 4 byte long, you have to shift the value of green 8 bytes to the left (two hex values) and the value of red 16 bytes. After that you can simply add them up.

```
int rgb = (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
```

### Getting from BottomUp to TopDown

I know the terminology bottom-up -> top-down is not correct here, but it was catchy.

To access 2D data in a 1D array you usually use some formula (this case row-major order) like

```
int index = offset + (y - yOffset) * stride + (x - xOffset);
```

Since you want to have the complete image the offsets can be left out and the formula simplified to

```
int index = y * stride + x;
```

Of course the `stride` is simply the `WIDTH`, i.e. the maximum achievable `x` value (or in other terms the row length).

The problem you now face is that OpenGL uses the bottom row as row 0 while the BufferedImage uses the top row as row 0. To get rid of that problem just invert y:

```
int index = ((HEIGHT - 1) - y) * WIDTH + x;
```

### Filling the int[]-array with the Buffer's Data

Now you know how to calculate the rgb value, the correct index and you have all data you need. Let's fill the int[]-array with those information.

```
int[] rgbArray = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
    for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) {
        int r = (int)(imageData.get() * 255) << 16;
        int g = (int)(imageData.get() * 255) << 8;
        int b = (int)(imageData.get() * 255);
        int i = ((HEIGHT - 1) - y) * WIDTH + x;
        rgbArray[i] = r + g + b;
    }
}
```

Note three things about this little piece of code.

1. The size of the array. Obviously it's just `WIDTH * HEIGHT` and not `WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3` as the buffer's size was.
2. Since OpenGL uses row-major order, you have to use the column value (x) as the inner loop for this 2D array (and of course there are other ways to write this, but this seemed to be the most intuitive one).
3. Accessing imageData with `imageData.get()` is probably not the safest way to do it, but since the calculations are carefully done it should do the job just fine. Just remember to `flip()` or `rewind()` the buffer before calling `get()` the first time!

### Putting it all together

So with all the information available now we can just put a method `saveScreenshot()` together.

```
private void saveScreenshot() {
    // read current buffer
    FloatBuffer imageData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3); 
    GL11.glReadPixels(
        0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_FLOAT, imageData
    );
    imageData.rewind();

    // fill rgbArray for BufferedImage
    int[] rgbArray = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x) {
            int r = (int)(imageData.get() * 255) << 16;
            int g = (int)(imageData.get() * 255) << 8;
            int b = (int)(imageData.get() * 255);
            int i = ((HEIGHT - 1) - y) * WIDTH + x;
            rgbArray[i] = r + g + b;
        }
    }

    // create and save image
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
         WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB
    );
    image.setRGB(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, rgbArray, 0, WIDTH);
    File outputfile = getNextScreenFile();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Can not save screenshot!");
    }
}

private File getNextScreenFile() {
    // create image name
    String fileName = "screenshot_" + getSystemTime(false);
    File imageToSave = new File(fileName + ".png");

    // check for duplicates
    int duplicate = 0;
    while(imageToSave.exists()) {
        imageToSave = new File(fileName + "_" + ++duplicate + ".png");
    }

    return imageToSave;
}

// format the time
public static String getSystemTime(boolean getTimeOnly) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
      getTimeOnly?"HH-mm-ss":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss"
    );
    return dateFormat.format(new Date());
}
```

I also uploaded a very simple [full working example](http://pastebin.com/jwvyTcFp).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I already had it working, but I also tried yours and it is much clearer and easier to use! +1 to you!

Comment: Also, here's my Util.getSystemTime(boolean getOnlyTime) function: http://redsandbox.no-ip.org/Files/get_system_time.java so now you can use that function instead of using System.getCurrentTimeMillis(), which is just a bunch of random numbers when looking for a specific date.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I allowed myself to shorten it a little and use a slightly different format - but that's just a matter of taste. I also updated my example code to reflect those changes.

Comment: Cool, nice usage of tertiary operators. I like using them, but I always wait until I have rounded out my code and gotten it working before I start making it 'efficient'. In that case, however, tertiary operators are cool. Thanks for all the help! I have a couple of other unanswered questions, would you be willing to take a crack at them?